# Angular 6: Can't bind api data to var in client

Tags: typescript, express, mongoose, angular6

i'm having trouble binding requested api-data to a variable in my component.

So first, my serverside method (using express and mongoose)

```
    app.post('/api/rolloutMeeting', async (req, res)=> {
    var singleMeetingID = req.body
    singleMeetingID = singleMeetingID.singleMeetingID
    var meeting = []

    meeting[0] = await Meeting.findOne({_id: singleMeetingID})
    companyID = meeting[0].compID.compID

    meeting[1] = []
    for(var i = 0; i < meeting[0].projectIDs.length+1; i++) {
        meeting[1][i] = await Project.findOne({_id: meeting[0].projectIDs[i]})
    }

    meeting[2] = []
    for(var j = 0; j < meeting[1][j].taskIDs.length; j++) {
        for(var k = 0; k < meeting[1][j].taskIDs.length; k++) {
            meeting[2][j] = await Content.findOne({_id: meeting[1][j].taskIDs[j]})
        }
    }

    console.log(meeting)

    res.json(meeting)
})
```

The output is working fine and exactly as i wanted.

This is my Service Method that requests the data from the api.

```
  rolloutMeeting(singleMeetingID) {
    return this.http.post('/api/rolloutMeeting', {
      singleMeetingID
    })
  }
```

And finally my component where most-likely the mistake is hidden:

```
      import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { MeetingService } from '../../meeting.service';
import { ProjectService } from '../../project.service';
import { ContentService } from '../../content.service'
import { meeting } from '../../meeting'
import { project } from '../../project';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-singlemeeting',
  templateUrl: './singlemeeting.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./singlemeeting.component.css']
})
export class SinglemeetingComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() singleMeetingID: String;

  constructor(private meetServ: MeetingService,
    private proServ: ProjectService,
    private taskServ: ContentService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData()
  }

  getData() {
    this.meetServ.rolloutMeeting(this.singleMeetingID)
      .subscribe(data => this.meeting : any = data)
    console.log(this.meeting)
  }

  tasks = []
  projects = []
  meeting : any
}
```

Now when I do this:
.subscribe(data => console.log(data)) im getting the exact output as when im console.logging the meeting array on my server.

I made a lot of different attempts to bind it to my meeting Array in the Client like:

```
.subscribe(data => this.meeting = data[0] as meeting)
```

and

```
.subscribe(data => this.meeting = data as meeting)
```

and

```
    .subscribe(data => function {
    this.meeting = data
})
```

Also for each try, I initialised the meeting var as any, as array and without any declaration.

However, none of those tries seemed to work for me, console.log(this.meeting) always gives me undefined, while console.log(data) always returns the answer i actually want to have.

What I want to do is, putting data[0] into a meeting variable and running my meeting interface over it, data[1] into project Array with project interface and so on...

Thanks for trying to anyone who reads this.

Best Regards

Comment: show component where ` this.meeting ` is defined (show it definition)

Comment: I tried to define it as   meeting : any, meeting, and meeting = [ ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show definition of meeting type and your controler class but try

```
.subscribe(data => { this.meeting = data; console.log(this.meeting) } )
```

The problem that `console.log` shows `undefined` is because callback function inside subscribe is run asynchronously (AFTER next line of code: console.log) - so if you put console.log inside callback, then you will see result

You can also use following construction with async/await:

```
async getData() {
    this.meeting = await this.meetServ.rolloutMeeting(this.singleMeetingID).toPromise();
    console.log(this.meeting)
}
```

but you should be aware that in fact code after await (console.log) will run asynchronously after data was loaded (so this is something like syntax sugar which make that your asynchronous code looks like synchronous so it is less nested)

Comment: added the whole component instead of a snippet. This doesn't work for me though.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, but how do i make it accessible outside of the subscribe function since I want to use it in my component.html to output the data in the meeting Array?

Comment: @J1297 the data are accesible outside subscribe! But not immediatley (as I say) but after some time (when server return response) - and If you use it in template by eg. `<div *ngIf="meeting">Data are loaded: {{ meeting | json }}</div>` the angular will detect changes of `meeting` value and show above div.